# I want regex to match a pattern that can only have either two alphabet characters or numeric characters

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex for PHP that can match two alphabetic characters or two numeric characters. For example:

**AB** or **45**

*The characters can't be mixed with alphabetic and numeric.*

```
^(\w)\1|[A-Z|0-9]{2}$
```

I used the above regex but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: `preg_match('~^(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|\d{2})$~', $s)`?

Comment: For something so simple, regex seems to be an overkill for me.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. it worked (?:[A-Za-z]{2}|\d{2})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match('~^(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|\d{2})$~', $s, $match)
```

The `^(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|\d{2})$` pattern matches two ASCII letters or two ASCII digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wDgfYx/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5BA-Za-z%5D%7B2%7D%7C%5Cd%7B2%7D)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|\d{2})` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `[A-Za-z]{2}` - two ASCII letters
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{2}` - two digits
- `$` - end of string.

To make it match all Unicode letters, you may use

```
preg_match('~^(?:\p{L}{2}|[0-9]{2})$~u', $s, $match)
```

Comment: What does `?:` mean here?

Comment: @ImaginaryPumpkin See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad. The string itself is the entire captured thing and maybe you used `?:` for performance reasons.

Comment: @vivek_23 Just best practice and force of habit.